# PHP / Laravel - Unique Results for shared relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to create a web application, where users can:

1. Upload documents
2. Upload emails (inbound emails)

The documents/emails will be uploaded to what I call a "Stream". So a stream can have many documents and many emails stored.

However, I am furthermore trying to do so my users can parse the content of the documents and emails, according to a set of parsing rules. The users can create **fields** that can have many parsing rules.

**Example:**
User A uploads a new document to a stream called "My Documents and Emails". The user have defined below two *document fields*  for this stream:

1. Order Reference
2. Tracking Number

Further, there are some *email fields* that has been defined as well, **but will not be used in this case, as User A is currently uploading a new document**:

1. From Name
2. Email Subject

All fields above will also have some parsing rules, that will parse the content (this is not shown in this example, as it is not relevant).

As you can see, the stream "My Documents and Emails" both have `DocumentFields` and `EmailFields`.

This is my current setup:

`Stream.php`

```
//A stream can have many document fields
public function documentfields()
{
    return $this->hasMany(DocumentField::class);
}
//A stream can have many email fields
public function emailfields()
{
    return $this->hasMany(EmailField::class);
}
```

`Document.php` (Same relationship are avialable in `Email.php`)

```
//A document belongs to a Stream.
public function stream()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Stream::class);
}

//Get the document fields available for the specific stream.
public function fields()
{
   return $this->stream->documentfields();
}
```

Now my question is, how can I do so the fields are "bound" to the stream, but contain a unique value for each `Document` or `Email` that is uploaded?

Something like:

`document_fields`:

```
id | stream_id          | name             
1  | 1                  | Order Reference 
2  | 1                  | Tracking Number
```

`document_field_results`

```
id | document_field_id  | document_id  | content
1  | 1                  | 10           | Lorem Ipsum Dolar Amet for document #10    
2  | 2                  | 10           | Some other Lorem Ipsum Dolar Amet for document #10
3  | 1                  | 55           | Lorem Ipsum Dolar Amet for document #55       
4  | 2                  | 55           | Some other Lorem Ipsum Dolar Amet for document #55
```

(Same logic when uploading an email / inbound email)

So whenever a new document is uploaded to the stream (`id.1`), it will "inherit" the document fields above, but the content will be unique for each field (as each uploaded document/email will ultimately have different content).

What would the correct relationship setup look like in this case? And is this the correct way to go?

Comment: That's called Polymorphic relationship, check: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships look for "Polymorphic"

Comment: Its indeed called Polymorphic association the way it is designed here, but that is not needed IMO. I don't know Lavarel, I am just thinking out of the box in term of database modeling.Your `document fields` and `email fields`, are in essence the same thing: `fields`. So you should not split them into separate entities. They should all be be stored as fields, with a **type** describing them (property for your class / column for the DB table) that have either value `email` or  `document`. Then the results you want are easy to get with a SQL query.

Comment: @ThomasG check out my answer, I hope that is what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO.

`streams: id, name`

`file_categories: id, name`. Values: document & email. This gives you the flexibility to add new kind of file uploads

`uploads: id, file_category_id, stream_id ,name`

`upload_fields: id, stream_id, name`

`upload_upload_fields: id, upload_id, upload_field_id, content`.

With this setup, you don't need to make models for Email and Document. Moreover, you can easily add new upload file category.

Btw, I've been programming for a while now, but just started to answering SO questions. I don't know how to make the database structure looks nice like in your questions. Could you give me a link to that format?

## Implementation

I am not sure how the front end looks like. So I just go with my interpretation

Stream.php:

```
public function uploadFields(){
    return $this->hasMany(UploadField::class);
}
```

### New file uploads

```
//First, get the uploadFields based on the stream_id
$uploadFields = Stream::with('uploadFields')->get();

//Second, insert the upload
$upload = new Upload(bla bla bla...); 
$upload->save();
//https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#inserts
//Third, use the upload id to fill the upload_upload_fields, or if you prefer the result terms, that's okay
foreach($uploadFields as $field){
    UploadUploadField::insert(['upload_id' => $upload->id, 'upload_file_id' => $field->id, 'content' => 'The Lorem Ipsum, I guess this is from the request']);
}
```

I think that's how I am gonna do it. It will be a little bit different especially for the `content` since it highly depends on the `request` structure.

Comment: @thomas-g mentioned about `type` in his comment. I go for `category`

Comment: Appreciate your answer - however the naming for `upload_upload_fields` seems a bit odd?

Can you maybe share a bit, how I would use the relationships with code?

Comment: Yeah it's a bit odd. But it could save you time in figuring out the relationship. However, you can still use the `result` term. So it's gonna be `upload_field_results`, but in the long run, you will have to open the file to figure out the relationship.

Comment: Let me update my answer on how can you use it with code.

Comment: Thanks! However I am still a bit unsure about the `UploadUpload` naming - doesn't really makes sense to me in terms of readable code. Like what does `UploadUploadField` refer to?

Comment: Like I said, you could change it to upload_field_results

Comment: It's just a matter of preference, as for me, upload_upload_field is the most readable. Because I know that it's the relationship between Upload and UploadField. If you are not comfortable with that, just go with the UploadFieldResult

Comment: why not go for upload_fields and uploaded_fields,